# Какой базовый класс view в c#

Tags: c#

Какой класс является предком всех классов view(Button, Label, PictureBox и т. д.)?

Comment: `Object`, `Component`, `Control`, вам какой больше нравится? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: А для чего вам нужно?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c)